# averaging 12 bit adc values using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, hdl

I have a question related to continuous averaging of ADCs value. The approach that I used is continuous averaging of example 256 samples. The ''adc_a_out'' value(shown in the code below) that I receive on my GUI increments slowly. As an example, if I am expecting value 100mA, My GUI shows 4mA, 8mA, 15mA,...... and then finally after 2 minutes I get stable 100mA value. I want to see the 100mA directly on my GUI from 'adc_a_out' instead of increment values and stabilizing after sometime. Another question is that, Can I somehow make this process fast so that I don't have to wait for 3 minutes for receiving stable 100 mA from adc_a_out. The clock 'clk' in the digital design below is 20 MHz. The clock for receiving ADC values on the FPGA board is 15 KHz.

```
--adc_top_file.vhd

entity adc_block_1 is 
  port (
        clk      : in  std_logic;  
        reset    : in  std_logic;              

        data_in  : in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        req      : in  std_logic;
        adc_a_1    : inout std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  
        adc_b_1    : inout std_logic_vector (11 downto 0); 
        slv_value1    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  
        slv_value2    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  

  );
end adc_block_1;

architecture adc_top_block of adc_block_1 is 

component adc is 
  port (
        clk      : in  std_logic;  
        reset    : in  std_logic;           

        data_in  : in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        req      : in  std_logic;
        adc_a_1    : inout std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  
        adc_b_1    : inout std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
        adc_a_1_temp: out signed(11 downto 0);
        adc_b_1_temp: out signed(11 downto 0);   
        slv_value1    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  
        slv_value2    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  

  );
end component;



component use_moving_average is

port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        channel_1_sample: in signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_2_sample: in signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_1_average: inout signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_2_average: inout signed(11 downto 0);
        slv_value1    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  
        slv_value2    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0)
    );
end component;

  signal adc_a_1_temp   : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  signal adc_b_1_temp   : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);

  signal adc_a_1_out   : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  signal adc_b_1_out   : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);


begin

  inst_adc : adc 
  port map (
        clk      => clk,  
        reset    => reset,          

        req  => adc_req,
        adc_a_1    => adc_a_1_temp,
        adc_b_1    => adc_b_1_temp,
        adc_a_1_temp    => adc_a_1_temp,
        adc_b_1_temp    => adc_b_1_temp

  );

inst_moving_average : use_moving_average
    port map (
    clock  => clk,
        reset  => reset,
        channel_1_sample  => adc_a_1_temp,
        channel_2_sample  => adc_b_1_temp,
        channel_1_average => adc_a_1_out,
        channel_2_average => adc_b_1_out,
        slv_value1        => slv_value1,
        slv_value2        => slv_value2
    );
```

-- the adc.vhd file is below:

```
     data_in  : in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
     adc_a_1 : inout std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  
     adc_b_1 : inout std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
     adc_a_1_temp: out signed(11 downto 0);
     adc_b_1_temp: out signed(11 downto 0); 
     load   : out std_logic;  

    process (clk, reset)

    begin
        if (reset = '1') then 
        state<=idle;
        adc_out1=0;
        adc_out2 <= 0;

        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
        case state is

    when idle =>
        if req='1' then 
        state= out_1;
        end if;

    when out_1 =>
        if done='1' then
        data_out <= addr0 & bits;
        adc_a_1 <= data_in(11 downto 0);
        adc_a_1_temp <= signed(adc_a_1);

        state <= out_2;
        endif;

    when out_2 =>
       if done='1' then
       adc_b_1 <= data_in(11 downto 0);
       adc_b_1_temp <= signed(adc_b_1);

       state <= done_st;

    when done_st =>
        ack <='1';
        --load <='1';
        state <= idle;

    when others =>
        state <= idle;
        end case;
        end if;
        end process;

load: process (clk, reset)
  begin
    if (reset = '1') then
      load <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        max_cnt <= 5000000;
        load <= '0';
      else
        max_cnt <= max_cnt -1;
        load <= '1';
    end if;
  end process load;
```

Your code is modified as follows:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity use_moving_average is
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        channel_1_sample: in signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_2_sample: in signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_1_average: inout signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_2_average: inout signed(11 downto 0);
        slv_value1    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);  
        slv_value2    : out std_logic_vector (11 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture rtl of use_moving_average is
    signal average_1, average_2: integer;
begin

    channel_1: entity work.moving_average
        port map(
            sample  => to_integer(channel_1_sample),
            average => average_1,
            clock   => clock,
            reset   => reset
        );

    channel_2: entity work.moving_average
        port map(
            sample  => channel_2_sample,
            average => average_2,
            clock   => clock,
            reset   => reset
        );

    channel_1_average <= to_signed(average_1, 12);
    slv_value1 <= std_logic_vector(channel_1_average);
    channel_2_average <= to_signed(average_2, 12);
    slv_value2 <= std_logic_vector(channel_2_average);
end;
```

The final output that I am viewing on my GUI is 'slv_value1' and 'slv_value2'

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: at reset (or at any other time if you want), assign the `data_in` value to **all** elements in you `stage` array. This should instantly set your average to the current value:

```
process (clk, reset) 
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        out_val <= 0;
        stage <= (others => data_in(11 downto 0));
        sum <= resize(255 * signed(data_in(11 downto 0)), sum'length);
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        ...
```

The example below shows the complete code for a moving average calculator. My suggestion is that you study it until you understand it. Then, try to use it in your design. Finally, and only after you have a basic circuit working, you could change it to satisfy your design constraints (data width, number of samples, range of integers, use of `signed` vs. `integer`, etc.)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity moving_average is
    generic(
        SAMPLES_COUNT: integer := 256
    );
    port (
        sample: in integer;
        average: out integer;
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic
    );
end;

architecture rtl of moving_average is

    signal samples_fifo: integer_vector(1 to SAMPLES_COUNT);
    signal sum: integer;

begin

    process (clock, reset) begin
        if reset then
            samples_fifo <= (others => sample);
            sum <= SAMPLES_COUNT * sample;
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            samples_fifo <= sample & samples_fifo(1 to SAMPLES_COUNT-1);
            sum <= sum + sample - samples_fifo(SAMPLES_COUNT);
        end if;
    end process;

    average <= sum / SAMPLES_COUNT;
end;
```

Finally, if you want to use the above code to keep two separate averages for two distinct signals, simply instantiate the averaging entity twice:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity use_moving_average is
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        channel_1_sample: in signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_2_sample: in signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_1_average: out signed(11 downto 0);
        channel_2_average: out signed(11 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture rtl of use_moving_average is
    signal average_1, average_2: integer;
begin

    channel_1: entity work.moving_average
        port map(
            sample  => to_integer(channel_1_sample),
            average => average_1,
            clock   => clock,
            reset   => reset
        );

    channel_2: entity work.moving_average
        port map(
            sample  => channel_2_sample,
            average => average_2,
            clock   => clock,
            reset   => reset
        );

    channel_1_average <= to_signed(average_1, 12);
    channel_2_average <= to_signed(average_2, 12);
end;
```

**Edit:** As I understand from your comments, you may need an extra input to set the average instantaneously to the current input value. In that case, you can use a `load` input as shown below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity moving_average is
    generic(
        SAMPLES_COUNT: integer := 256
    );
    port (
        sample: in integer;
        average: out integer;
        clock: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        load: in std_logic
    );
end;

architecture rtl of moving_average is

    signal samples_fifo: integer_vector(1 to SAMPLES_COUNT);
    signal sum: integer;

begin

    process (clock, reset) begin
        if reset then
            samples_fifo <= (others => sample);
            sum <= SAMPLES_COUNT * sample;
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            if load then
                samples_fifo <= (others => sample);
                sum <= SAMPLES_COUNT * sample;
            else
                samples_fifo <= sample & samples_fifo(1 to SAMPLES_COUNT-1);
                sum <= sum + sample - samples_fifo(SAMPLES_COUNT);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    average <= sum / SAMPLES_COUNT;
end;
```

Comment: I will now check the result on fpga and let u know. Will it also fast the process? I mean, will I get the value quickly because I get the stable value like 100mA after 2 minutes using above code.

Comment: With above code, I get following error:
Error (10327): VHDL error at adc.vhd(103): can't determine definition of operator ""*"" -- found 0 possible definitions

Comment: Did you try to include `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`?

Comment: Yes I did and I got the above error. I included following libraries:



library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

Comment: Now I get another error:
`Error (10344): VHDL expression error at adc.vhd(103): expression has 24 elements, but must have 20 elements`
it is talking about the following line:
`sum <= 255 * signed(data_in(11 downto 0));`

Comment: If now I increase `sum` from 20 bit to 24 bit, then how can I get the required adc value: `adc_a_out <= std_logic_vector(sum(19 downto 8));`

Comment: Yes, you will see this kind of error until you have the exact size of your signals sorted out. This is something that only you can do, knowing what you want to keep in each signal. You could try to resize the result with `sum <= resize(255 * signed(data_in(11 downto 0)), sum'length);` but only you can tell whether this is correct.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I still get the same result. My GUI shows 4mA, 8mA, 15mA,...... and then finally after 2 minutes I get stable 100mA value.

Comment: I can't post the complete code as it is very very long. I have added more details in the above code with some explanation. Please let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: I added to the answer the complete code for a moving average calculation. It is probably simpler than you'd think.

Comment: I have edited my code above without averaging the ADC output values. Can you tell me how can I average in parallel 'adc_out1' and 'adc_out2' values. I want to continuously average 256 samples of each of these outputs in parallel. Can you now merge your code with mine?

Comment: I don't understand why you need two output values. If you have two independent ADC values, and you want to calculate two separate averages, then just instantiate two instances of my sample code. Anyway, I've edited the answer to include an example that averages two ADC channels independently.

Comment: If I am not wrong, I have to do what I did above now. I have edited my code again. Just one thing where and how can I convert my std_logic_vector signal 'adc_a_1_out' to signed(11 downto 0)?

Comment: In your case, it is best to avoid using `std_logic_vector` and use `signed` wherever you can. Anyway, to convert a signal named *signed_value* (of *signed* type) to a signal named *slv_value* (of *std_logic_vector* type), you must write: `slv_value <= std_logic_vector(signed_value);`. This is called *type casting*.

Comment: Can you tell what is integer_vector in your moving average code. How it will be declared?

Comment: For integer_vector, turn on VHDL-2008.

Comment: I defined it as: type integer_vector is array (0 to 255) of integer; but it didn't work in the above code. Kindly tell me what is wrong in declaring like that.

Comment: The first choice would be to enable support for VHDL-2008 in your compiler. Other than that, try `type integer_vector is array (natural range <>) of integer;`. Also, when something doesn't work in the code, please describe the error message you are seeing.

Comment: I tried with `type integer_vector is array (0 to 255) of integer;` but it didn't work. I get the following error: `Error (10457): VHDL Subtype Declaration error at moving_average.vhd(18): subtype for constrained integer_vector type cannot have range
`

Comment: Try `type integer_vector is array (natural range <>) of integer;`

Comment: It worked for me. The code is running now. I can see the fast outputs as well. The problem is that, I am not getting the correct values. I have put the complete code above in my first post. Can you tell me if I am doing something wrong

Comment: I changed your averaged outputs to inout for conversion. Kindly check my updated code above with your code if it looks correct to you?

Comment: I woldn't change the code in the `moving_average` entity, it is better to do the conversions on your top-level file. As for why the results are wrong, you need to show the results you are getting. A picture with the simulation waveforms would be nice.

Comment: I checked the results on the FPGA. I didn't do the simulation yet. I will do it and let you know if there is anything wrong in it. But did anything look wrong in the above code?

Comment: Nothing that looks obviously wrong. But try to get into the habit of doing the simulations *before* testing the design on the FPGA, it is much easier to catch errors on the simulator.

Comment: @rick
I checked in the simulation and there was an issue of wiring. I fixed it. Now the only issue is in the stabilization. The values after the average block is not stable. There is a variation of 80mA in it. Is it possible that I can reduce the variation and get a stable value after the filter?

Comment: What is the range of your input values? (maximum value/minimum value in mA) And what is the scale of your ADC values? It is always possible to make the output more stable, but it will cost you a slower response time.

Comment: @rick If I set the DAC value to 1V, my ADC range is between 80mA and 140 mA. When I set the value to 1.2V, my ADC range is between 140mA and 190mA. Can you tell me here in this code, how can I make my values stable?

Comment: If you kept your code really generic, you just need to increase the value of SAMPLES_COUNT. If you are using 256, try 512 or 1024, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried with 512 but there was still variation. There was not a big difference when I changed from 256 to 512. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Keep doubling the value, until you notice a difference. I understand you get a new ADC value once every 1/15,000 seconds. This means that you may have to use a very high value of samples count. Another choice is to discard the least significant bits read from your ADC (i.e., use only 10 or 8 bits instead of 12).

Comment: I am checking with 1024 now. I will let you know if there is any difference. Can you tell me how can I use only 8 or 10 bits instead of 12 bits in my above code. Do u mean to do the following:
`channel_1_average <= to_signed(average_1, 10);
    channel_2_average <= to_signed(average_2, 10);`

Comment: I would say wherever you use `data_in(11 downto 0)`, try using `data_in(11 downto 2) & "00"` instead.

Comment: I tried with 1024 as well but still not much difference. Also I changed `data_in(11 downto 0)` to `data_in(11 downto 2) & "00"` and even changed `data_in(11 downto 0)` to `data_in(11 downto 4) & "0000"` but there is no difference at all.

Comment: @rick
do you have anyother idea what could be possible to make the output stable?

Comment: Then there is something in your design that you don't fully understand. I recommend that you go through it thoroughly and draw a diagram. I also recommend that you eliminate the component `use_moving_average`, and move its functionality to `adc_block_1`. Also, think about this: if the ADC outputs a new value every 1/15,000 of a second, then it takes 1 second to eliminate the influence of the last of the 15,000 samples. Because you are using only 1,024, you can't see much difference, because any sample is "forgotten" after only 68 milliseconds. Try to bump up SAMPLES_COUNT to 16,384 if you can.

Comment: @rick Can you tell me if it is possible to include the functionality of the filter in adc.vhd block instead of adc_block_1? How can I include the functionality in adc_block_1.vhd block?

Comment: Yes, but maybe you don't want to do that, because they have different purposes. It is good that you keep the averaging module separate. And honestly, I don't understand the purpose of your `adc` module. You should probably choose a more descriptive name for it. One last recommendation: try to name each file after the entity it describes. For instance, for `entity moving_average`, save it in a file named `moving_average.vhd`

Comment: Sweet! Maybe then you could update the code on your post because it shows `entity adc_block_1` in file `adc_top_file.vhd`

Comment: @rick
I have figured it out that my average block was not running at all because I was running it at 20MHz and the done signal coming from SPI block is running on 78KHz which means I get the next data_in after every 78KHz. I am now running my average block on CS (78kHz) coming from spi master instead of normal clock of 20MHz. Now I am getting the result like i-e 10mA, 20mA, 40mA,......100mA and the value gets stable after that. I want the 100mA directly. Can you now tell me how is it possible to do that. Do I have to further clock down my average block for that?

Comment: It is very simple to get an instantaneous update of the average. One alternative is to send a reset pulse to the `moving_average` entity. Another choice is to add an extra signal (say `load`), and modify the architecture to execute the same two statements (`samples_fifo <= (others => sample); sum <= SAMPLES_COUNT * sample;`) when `load` is asserted.

Comment: @rick
I cannot check it now. I will check it on monday and let you know. But can you tell me where to add the extra 'load' signal in my code? Also how and at what point to send a reset pulse to moving_average entity? Can you show me in your code? Thanks

Comment: @rick
Can you tell where to add the extra 'load' signal in my code? Also how and at what point to send a reset pulse to moving_average entity? Can you show me in your code? I will check that tomorrow. thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a `load` input. In your case, you may start by attaching the load signal to a push button on your board, to make sure it works as expected.

Comment: @rick can you also tell me how to send a reset pulse to moving_average entity in the code?

Comment: Your circuit should have a reset signal. It is common practice to connect all registers to the same signal.

Comment: @rick 
At what point should I make 'load' signal equal to '1'?

Comment: At the point where you want your output to go immediately to the current value of the ADC. Can you just connect it to a push-button or switch and do it manually, at least for now?

Comment: @rick Ok I will test that. Another question is about the reset signal to the moving_average entity. I am a little confused. The reset signal  is already connected to my moving_average entity block. Can you tell me what is missing in the code?

Comment: It seems like you have connected all reset ports to the same signal, so you should be ok. Using a different reset for the `moving_average` block was just a suggestion in case you didn't want to change that entity's code, but now that you've added the `load` port you don't need to touch its reset.

Comment: @rick The board was not free but I will check with that load signal and put it on switch but just for clarification and for testing, i am doing 'load=1' in adc.vhd file in the state done_st. Am I right? I modified the adc.vhd file as well in my post above.

Comment: @rick
Kindly let me know if I put the load=1 at correct place in my code?

Comment: Read in the code what will happend if keep `load` and a constant value `1`. You will come to the conclusion that the averaging part of the algorithm will never be executed. Your `load` must be a short pulse, like a button press, or the averaging will not work.

Comment: @rick
I checked it and with the above modification that I did, my average block doesnt run and I get the old values with variation. Can you tell me that at what point in my code I can make load=1 and load=0?

Comment: @rick
I put the load signal on the switch on the board and I checked it manually and it is working. I get the ADC value. Can you tell me now where can I make load=0 and load=1 in my code?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to connect `load` with `reset`, but you need to test if this will work for you. Otherwise, you could implement a counter, so that after (for instance) half a second it would generate a pulse that you would connect to the `load` port.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. If you think the answer was useful, could you click the checkmark next to it and mark it as the accepted answer?